# asp classic and select tag with multiple attribute

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am using select tag of html and having multiple attribute. and now I am fetching of selected option from the select tag using asp classic. but getting 500 internal server error.

```
<%
response.write(request("evtCategory").Count)
response.write(request("evtCategory"))
%>

<form id="frmSearch" method="post" >
<select name="evtCategory" multiple>
    <option value="0">--Select Category--</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
    <option value="5">Fifth</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your code works for me when testing.

Comment: Works for me too - could anything else on the page be causing the error?

Comment: IE --> Internet Options --> Advanced --> untick "Show friendly HTTP error messages" --> confirm. You will see now real error messages.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Count exists in Classic ASP, that looks like ASP.NET code.

Multiple selected values will be returned as a comma separated string.

You can use Split to get the selected values as an array.

```
Dim values, i
values = Split(Request.Form("evtCategory"), ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(values)
    Response.Write("Value " & i & " = " & values(i) & "<br />")
Next
```

Comment: `Count` definitely does exist. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx